# MS Access MDB-File keeps becoming corrupted

Tags: vba, ms-access, jet

We got a problem with Microsoft Access .mdb-files. After some time working with an .mdb-file in a multiuser environment the file becomes corrupted and has to be repaired. After it's repaired it takes less time to become corrupted again. And at some point after multiple reperations the file isn't usable at all anymore.

This problem started to appear after we changed from MS Access Runtime 2010 to MS Access Runtime 2013.

I've already spent some time looking into this problem and this is my theory:

The mdb-file appearently contains a "Database Header Page" (described in a White Paper from Microsoft called "Understanding Microsoft Jet Locking" from 1996) which saves information about the commit bytes of Users (important: 0000 = writing to disk, 0100 = accessed a corrupted page). And there is a paragraph in the white paper about this Database Header Page which explains exactly what is happening in our problem:

"[...]Therefore, if a value of 00 00 is present without corresponding user lock [this would be an entry in the corresponding .ldb-file I think], or a value of 0100 is present, users will not be allowed to connect to the database without first executing the repair utility."

So my guess is, that after some amount of loosing connection to the mdb/breaking the connection this Database Header Page overflows and you have to repair the file but the repair doesn't remove every entry inside of this Database Header Page, so the amount of broken connections needed for the file to become corrupted decreases until the file completely breaks.

Now I would like to know if this theory is any good and if it is I would like to know:

1. How can I test this theory (how can I read this Database Header Page of the mdb-file)?
2. Can I modify the Database Header Page?
3. Can  I modify the Database Header Page while someone is working with the mdb?

I know it's a very specific problem but I hope you guys can help me!

P.S. I can't find a link to the white paper but the "LDBViewer"-packet contains this white paper.

Comment: How your file used? Is it backend with local frontends for each user or this is single database, used by multiple users? In last case corruption probability is very high, you need to split the database

Comment: It is a single database used by multiple users, but it can't be splitted because of structural desicions.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to rework your database for splitting. Which limitations do you have which don't allow to split the database?

Comment: @SergeyS.is right; you'll have to reconsider the current setup and move to the recommended split setup. The frontend can be distributed using a script as described in my article [Deploy and update a Microsoft Access application in a Citrix environment](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/23959/Deploy-and-update-a-Microsoft-Access-application-in-a-Citrix-environment.html)

Comment: You speak about a multiuser environment, are these users at the same time busy in the databases? If these are concurrent users, are they also changing the data concurrent (creating, editing, deleting)?

Comment: Just to add one voice to the choir: a single file isn't a suitable environment for multi-user Access. Every hour you put into trying to solve this particular problem will ultimately be wasted. Distributed frontends plus shared backend (or DBMS) is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks for all your opinions/suggestions! I'm going to think about distributed frontends but it's beyond my position to decide if it's going to happen. Anyways thank you guys!

Answer (score 0):

A few quick and dirty tricks that I often use are enabled by creating a small database which serves one purpose: control how the desired target database is opened.
This database is copied to the desktop of every user, so every user/session has its own.

So I would have 
* 1 database on a server-location : `[TheBigOne.mdb]`
* 1 database copied to several desktops : `[TheCaller.mdb]`

--01-- :
Every morning, call a function which will perform the following steps :

`* rename [TheCaller.mdb] to [TheCaller-xxx.mdb]
* create and open [TheCaller-NEW.mdb]
* for all tables, queries, forms, reports, macros, modules
   DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, , [TheCaller-xxx.mdb], _
   acTable-acQuery-acForm-acReport-acMacro-acModule, "y", "y", False
* rename [TheCaller-NEW.mdb] to [TheCaller.mdb]`


--02--
Create a form in `[TheCaller.mdb]` with one button, with an `OnClick`-event like : 
`If Dir(ServerLocation & "\TheBigOnd.ldb") = "" Then
    'open [TheBigOne.mdb]
Then
    Msgbox "Database already in use!"
End If`

This is prone to a lot of headaches, because it will happen that the `[TheBigOnd.ldb]` file does exists, while no one is using the database. But at least, you will have less database-corruption.

--03--
An alternative for this procedure --02-- can be achieved by using a command-line switch `/excl`. At any given time, only one user will be able to work in the database.

--04--
Create a second button on the form from point --02--, which will open `[TheBigOne.mdb]` with command-line switch `/ro`. This will open the database in a read-only mode for this user, avoiding the corruption of the database.

--05--
Create a small backend database `db_sessions.mdb` on a server-location, with
a table in it like `T_Sessions(id, whois, started_at_timestamp, ended_at_timestamp, excl_or_ro, troubles)` for keeping track [who] [opens] and [closes] [when] the database `[TheBigOne.mdb]`.
If a user wants more priviliges then read-only, the following test has to be true: `DCount("*","T_Sessions","ended_at_timestamp is null AND excl_or_ro = 'excl'") = 0`. If this test results in `false`, the field `troubles` can be used to dispatch messages to other users.